# "Server error. Upload directory isn't writable."

Tags: php

I use `FineUpload` script to upload images on server. This is the code I use from **localhost**

```
<?php
require 'FineUpload.php';

$uploadDir = 'http://www.naukaplywaniakrakow.pl/gallery/';
$allowed   = explode(',', 'pdf');
$sizeLimit = 5000 * 1024;

$fineUpload = new FineUpload($allowed, $sizeLimit);
$response   = $fineUpload->handleUpload($uploadDir);

if (@$response['success']) {
    $uploadName = $fineUpload->getUploadName();

    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($uploadDir . $uploadName);

    $response['fileName'] = $uploadName;
}

echo json_encode($response);
```

I have created a `gallery` directory in `public_html` directory, but still gets the error:

> {"error":"Server error. Upload directory isn't writable."}

Comment: What does `ls -la` executed inside public_html return?

Comment: You have to use an absolute path to upload files to. Using a web address will not work.

Comment: Did you check the permissions of the directory to which you tried to upload?

Comment: @sujivasagam, I changed the permission of `/gallery` to `777` directly in admin panel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your upload directory must be a local folder relative to your current dir and not a web url.
Try `getcwd()` to know which folder you are in and then use a relative path to your `gallery` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try now.

```
<?php

require 'FineUpload.php';

$uploadDir = 'http://www.naukaplywaniakrakow.pl/gallery/';
$allowed   = explode(',', 'pdf');
$sizeLimit = 5000 * 1024;


$fineUpload = new FineUpload($allowed, $sizeLimit);
chmod($fineUpload,0777);
$response   = $fineUpload->handleUpload($uploadDir);

if (@$response['success']) {
    $uploadName = $fineUpload->getUploadName();

    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($uploadDir . $uploadName);

    $response['fileName'] = $uploadName;
}

echo json_encode($response);


?>
```